# Notification gets disappeared when phone is rebooted

Tags: android, notifications

I am working on alarms and making an app for task reminder.
I am showing notification at scheduled time by user.
But when alarm rings , notification appears . Then  I switched off my phone , and again when I switched , on the notification get disappeared(doesnt show the notification).
while in   the case of SMS notifiaction(default android implementation) it does not get disappeared until we drag  the notification.

I want the same as like sms  notification.
What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notifications are not persistent across device boots. If they reappear for certain apps, it's because the app is starting on boot and re-creating them.

You should define a receiver that determines if the notification should be present and creates it if necessary, and start this receiver on device boot.

Set its intent filter for,

```
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

and use permission,

```
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

and make sure your receiver has permission,

```
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Like this,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
...
<receiver ... android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: how about iOS? this happens also in iOS

Comment: There is a typo in this answer, it is not ""android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED" but "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".